# No return value from an AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a  AWS Lambda function that passes a set of parameters to another function; after some processing, this second function should return a value, but for some reason the first function does not receive that value.

This is the caller function:

```
import boto3

lam = boto3.client('lambda')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  payload={}
  payload['key1'] = 'Test Value'
  response=lam.invoke(FunctionName='callee', InvocationType='RequestResponse', Payload=json.dumps(payload))
  print(response)
```

This is callee function:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print('value1=' + event['key1'])
    return event['key1']
```

The callee function prints the value as expected, but caller function does not receive the return from callee.

How can I fix this? 
Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't the `callee` function be called `callee` instead of `lambda_handler`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `response` object comes back as:

```
{
    'ResponseMetadata': {...}, 
    'StatusCode': 200, 
    'ExecutedVersion': '$LATEST', 
    'Payload': <botocore.response.StreamingBody object at 0x7f34aea2d240>
}
```

You can then extract the return value via:

```
print(response['Payload'].read())
```